# Start forge server on arch linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, aur, minecraft

I installed the latest version of minecraft forge server over the AUR.

```
1 aur/forge-server 1.15.2_31.1.0-1 (+2 0.11%) (Installed)
    Minecraft Forge server unit files, script and jar
```

I can't seem to start it tho?
I tried to run `forge`,`forge-server` and `forge-server-1.15.2` - but it tells me command not found?
How am I supposed to start the forge server?

My goal is to setup a minecraft server on my system. And because I want to install the [mc-eternal](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/minecraft-eternal) modpack, I assume I need forge, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, the forge file is a java file and you will need to do something like this

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar forge_minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

where Xms and Xmx is the initial and maximum memory size for Java.

I would recommend you take a look at the link below.

https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server